# MySQL multiply two tables having different dimensions

Tags: mysql

I am having following two tables:

```
------------
| baseline |
------------
|   100   |
```

And

```
------------------------
|  conf_name  |  perc  |
------------------------
|    conf1    |   21   |
------------------------
|    conf2    |   50   |
------------------------
|    conf3    |   10   |
------------------------
|    conf4    |   30   |
```

I want to multiply `baseline` to `perc` column. So that the final table looks like:

```
    -----------------------------------
    |  conf_name  |  perc  |  target  |
    -----------------------------------
    |    conf1    |   21   |   2100   |
    -----------------------------------
    |    conf2    |   50   |   5000   |
    -----------------------------------
    |    conf3    |   10   |   1000   |
    -----------------------------------
    |    conf4    |   30   |   3000   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your value `100` it is very easy.

You can add another column:

```
select table2.*,table2.perc*100 as target from table2;
```

You can do it another way, but I will not recommend because the join in this case it is not needed.

```
select table2.*,table2.perc*table1.baseline as target from table2 join table1;
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be9a6c0/1

Comment: The value under baseline is variable, so it can't be fixed in the query.

Comment: @Nee If it is so use the second query, the result will be the same

Comment: But, both the tables do not have common ids/primary keys.